# C stack smashing detected in array

Tags: c

I am trying to solve a question.

If in array a number is duplicated I make him 0. My code is throwing an error could you please help me ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int a[] = {-3, -2, -1, -7, -3, 2, 3, 4, 2, 7, 10, 3}; 
int length = 12; 

int zero_duplicates(int laenge, int *a) {
    int zero[] = {};
    int k = 0;
    int j = 1;

    for(int x=0; x<laenge; x++)
    {
        if (zero[*a] == 1) {
            *a = 0;
        } else {
            zero[*a] = 1;
            k++;
        }
        a++;
    }
return k;
}


int count = zero_duplicates(length, a); 


printf("%d -- ", count); 

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) printf(" %i ", a[i]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This `int zero[] = {}` is defining an array of *zero* length, then this `zero[*a]` is accessing some index in that zero-length array. This can only cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I think such "zero-sized arrays" are a GNU extension - not sure how they work, though. But there are other issues with the code: Defining a function (`zero_duplicates`) ***inside*** another function (`main`) is not allowed in C.

Comment: @AdrianMole yeah, but they are only meaningful as the last element of a structure, to create dynamically sizeable arrays. OP's code is definitely invalid. Functions in functions are also a compiler extension.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I agree 100%. Just pointing out potential issues. (There are many: like `j` is never used.)

Comment: Have you checked your for loop? Try i < length - 1 ;

Comment: @MarcoBonelli in fact it's a constraint violation

Comment: @MarcoBonelli J is never used is not an error

Comment: @Grantly yes doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

This ...

> ```
>     int zero[] = {};
> ```

... is not a valid array declaration in C.  If your compiler accepts it as an extension then it ought at least to be emitting a warning, and even then it probably doesn't mean what you think it means.  Specifically, among the most likely extensions would be to interpret that as declaring a *zero-length* array (which also would constitute an extension), such that accessing any element overruns the array bounds.

Moreover, no matter how long the array is, if any of the elements of the input array are negative (as is the case in the example) then `zero[*a]` will constitute an out-of-bounds access when `a` points to one of those elements.

Overall, you need a different approach.  What you're trying to do is not viable.

As a separate matter, C does not support nested functions, so your code is relying on yet another extension in that respect.  This particular issue can be resolved by lifting the nested function out of `main()`, however, putting it above instead of inside.